# pipenv Failing to Install Packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipenv, pythonpath

So this error happened after I uninstalled Python 3.7.4 for the newer Python 3.8.3. I try to use `pipenv install` and this is what it outputs:

```
PS C:\Users\enoch\Documents\spectral_curve_calculator> pipenv install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\enoch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\python.py", line 618, in parse_executable
    result_version = get_python_version(path)
  File "C:\Users\enoch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\utils.py", line 105, in get_python_version      
    c = subprocess.Popen(version_cmd, **subprocess_kwargs)
  File "c:\users\enoch\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "c:\users\enoch\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\enoch\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\enoch\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\enoch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\pipenv.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\enoch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\enoch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\enoch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "C:\Users\enoch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\Users\enoch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\enoch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\decorators.py", line 73, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\enoch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\enoch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\decorators.py", line 21, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\enoch\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pipenv\cli\command.py", line 232, in install
    retcode = do_install(
  File "c:\users\enoch\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 1921, in do_install
    ensure_project(
  File "c:\users\enoch\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 576, in ensure_project
    ensure_virtualenv(
  File "c:\users\enoch\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 498, in ensure_virtualenv
    python = ensure_python(three=three, python=python)
  File "c:\users\enoch\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 388, in ensure_python
    path_to_python = find_a_system_python(python)
  File "c:\users\enoch\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 350, in find_a_system_python
    return next(iter(finder.find_all_python_versions()), None)
  File "c:\users\enoch\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\pythonfinder.py", line 312, in find_all_python_versions
    python_version_dict = getattr(self.system_path, "python_version_dict", {})
  File "c:\users\enoch\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\pythonfinder.py", line 120, in system_path
    self._system_path = self.create_system_path()
  File "c:\users\enoch\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\pythonfinder.py", line 82, in create_system_path
    return pyfinder_path.SystemPath.create(
  File "C:\Users\enoch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\path.py", line 682, in create
    instance = instance._run_setup()
  File "C:\Users\enoch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\path.py", line 233, in _run_setup
    new_instance = new_instance._setup_windows()
  File "C:\Users\enoch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\path.py", line 411, in _setup_windows
    windows_finder = WindowsFinder.create()
  File "C:\Users\enoch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\windows.py", line 146, in create
    return cls()
  File "<attrs generated init pythonfinder.models.windows.WindowsFinder>", line 13, in __init__
  File "C:\Users\enoch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\windows.py", line 113, in get_versions
    versions[py_version.version_tuple[:5]] = base_dir
  File "C:\Users\enoch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\python.py", line 365, in __getattribute__
    result = super(PythonVersion, self).__getattribute__(key)
  File "C:\Users\enoch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\python.py", line 430, in version_tuple
    self.patch,
  File "C:\Users\enoch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\python.py", line 375, in __getattribute__
    instance_dict = self.parse_executable(executable)
  File "C:\Users\enoch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\python.py", line 620, in parse_executable
    raise ValueError("Not a valid python path: %r" % path)
ValueError: Not a valid python path: 'C:/Users/enoch/Downloads/WPy64-3741/python-3.7.4.amd64/Scripts/python.exe'
```

So it seems that the issue happens since it is still trying to reference my old python location even though I already uninstalled it: `ValueError: Not a valid python path: 'C:/Users/enoch/Downloads/WPy64-3741/python-3.7.4.amd64/Scripts/python.exe'` I checked my environment variables and paths through control panel; they all point to my new Python 3.8.3 installation. Printing `sys.path`, it also never mentions the path of my previous installation. Does anyone have any idea of what's going on? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem.
You can try to go to regedit, and find the key word "python-3.7.4", delete all of them, and retry.

Answer (score 1):

Met the exact same error.
Ultimately, I solved this problem by simply deleting the duplicate python version using control panel.
But since you have already deleted the older version, then here is what I have been through, hope it would help.

---

### Python.py

Since the traceback is all about a wrong path, I followed the error message and dug into this `pythonfinder\models\python.py` file.
In there I found a method called `parse_executable(cls, path)`.  
I threw a `print(path)` in and it seems that the `path` variable was printed twice.

- One for the normal python in my PATH.
- Another for the old python path, python2.x, **even it is not in my PATH variable**

I play around with this file for a while, trying to figure out how the `path` is created and why it includes the zombie python2.x version that's not even a valid python path.

Though barely understand the logic, I thought what happened would be like:

- `parse_executable() > python 3.8 >`
- `check another version > parse_executable() > python 2.x > traceback`

### Registries

In order to solve the problem, I started to browse the internet. And [this](https://superuser.com/questions/433897/python-in-command-line-runs-the-wrong-version) blog pointed out how the **registry** could come into play.

I followed this answer and found the registries related to python in my machine are completely wrong. My python version should be 3.8, but it is 2.x

[image]

So I deleted all the `python.` registries. The data in them is wrong.

[image]

This may not be recommended and I am sorry I can't explain this well. Because I just thought this could be related without considering how important the registries are... You can refer to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/433897/python-in-command-line-runs-the-wrong-version) post to find out how to do.

### Desperate shots

After that, pipenv was still not working. And this `parse_executable(cls, path)` still printed two paths. I tried a lot to make sure that the python2.x was not in any possible paths.

- I deleted `{user}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python` folder.
- I deleted `{user}\AppData\Local\Roaming\Python37` folder.(I didn't know it exists...)

But still, python2.x was considered by `python.py`.

After all the struggling, I figured maybe this is not the issue about path, but the existing of a program. So I uninstalled the python2.x version in my machine. Surprisingly this desperate shot worked at last.

In short, I think the problem is incompletely uninstall the older python version, which may include the registries. I hope this could provide you a hint of why this error happened and how to solve it completely.

ps: I am still curious about how `python.py` could find the version of python2.x which is not in any environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this could save someone's time. 
My machine OS is Windows 10. I had the same problem, and the problem was caused by renamed executable, namely `python.exe` was named as `python2.exe`. The module `python.py` looks for `python.exe` in default locations, and after not finding it there raises the exception. So the solution in my case was to change the name to `python.exe`.

To see the default location of each python version use the following code:

```py
>>> import os
>>> import sys
>>> print(os.path.dirname(sys.executable))
```

If you're curious about how I figured that out. Look inside the `python.py`, the following code determines that very path('C:/Users/enoch/Downloads/WPy64-3741/python-3.7.4.amd64/**Scripts/python.exe**') which is displayed in the error messages:

```py
def from_windows_launcher(cls, launcher_entry, name=None, company=None):
        ...
        default_path = base_path / "python.exe"
        if not default_path.exists():
            default_path = base_path / "Scripts" / "python.exe"
```

As you can see it looks for `python.exe` and in my case it was named as `python2.exe`.