# Why "pipenv install requests" command on windows powershell is showing error?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I have already installed python's latest version and pipenv on Windows Powershell. When I try to install requests it is showing this error:

**FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified**

**ValueError: Not a valid python path: 'C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python.exe'**

Full error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\python.py", line 618, in parse_executable
    result_version = get_python_version(path)
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\utils.py", line 105, in get_python_version
    c = subprocess.Popen(version_cmd, **subprocess_kwargs)
  File "c:\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "c:\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python39\Scripts\pipenv.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\decorators.py", line 73, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\decorators.py", line 21, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pipenv\cli\command.py", line 233, in install
    retcode = do_install(
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 1920, in do_install
    ensure_project(
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 576, in ensure_project
    ensure_virtualenv(
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 498, in ensure_virtualenv
    python = ensure_python(three=three, python=python)
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 388, in ensure_python
    path_to_python = find_a_system_python(python)
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 350, in find_a_system_python
    return next(iter(finder.find_all_python_versions()), None)
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\pythonfinder.py", line 312, in find_all_python_versions
    python_version_dict = getattr(self.system_path, "python_version_dict", {})
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\pythonfinder.py", line 120, in system_path
    self._system_path = self.create_system_path()
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\pythonfinder.py", line 82, in create_system_path
    return pyfinder_path.SystemPath.create(
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\path.py", line 682, in create
    instance = instance._run_setup()
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\path.py", line 233, in _run_setup
    new_instance = new_instance._setup_windows()
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\path.py", line 411, in _setup_windows
    windows_finder = WindowsFinder.create()
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\windows.py", line 146, in create
    return cls()
  File "<attrs generated init pythonfinder.models.windows.WindowsFinder>", line 13, in __init__
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\windows.py", line 113, in get_versions
    versions[py_version.version_tuple[:5]] = base_dir
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\python.py", line 365, in __getattribute__
    result = super(PythonVersion, self).__getattribute__(key)
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\python.py", line 430, in version_tuple
    self.patch,
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\python.py", line 375, in __getattribute__
    instance_dict = self.parse_executable(executable)
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\python.py", line 620, in parse_executable
    raise ValueError("Not a valid python path: %r" % path)
ValueError: Not a valid python path: 'C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python.exe'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pipenv Failing to Install Packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62240644/pipenv-failing-to-install-packages)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have two different Python distributions installed on your system: the Python 3.9 in `C:\Python39\` and the Anaconda Python in `C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/`. There is a conflict between them.

I recommend that you use one of them only - the Anaconda or the official Python, and uninstall another.